# libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed?

Tags: release-juno, package-management

I get this message after installing any program via terminal 
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...

as seen in the image:[image]

note: i don't really know if this happens every time i install a program but it happened like 3 to 4 times
if anyone knows what is up with that feel free to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: You may safely remove `libdvd-pkg` with `sudo apt remove libdvd-pkg` if you don't run DVDs.

---

This is probably a problem with the package and doesn't seem to be a problem specific to elementary OS as it [also affects vanilla Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094062/libdvd-pkg-apt-get-check-failed-you-may-have-broken-packages-aborting). It's removal may affect if you run DVDs.

Answer (score 4):

all you have to do is:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Then a prompt will appear, you can use the "Tab" key on keyboard to select the option. Select "Yes" and press "Enter" key. If the next time you face this issue, select "No".

The original answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094062/libdvd-pkg-apt-get-check-failed-you-may-have-broken-packages-aborting)

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem.
And I discovered that the problem is in the installation of a ppa repository. Maybe you had been installing some programs with a new repository. You need to delete this one!